# Beacon Registered, but response indicates wrong UID

Tags: google-beacon-platform

I successfully registered a beacon using [Google Proximity API](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/guides?hl=en) but the response indicates a different UID

Request URL
https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons:register

**Request**

```
{
    "advertisedId": {
        "type": "EDDYSTONE",
        "id": "0x2f234454f4911ba9ffb6"
    },
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "latLng": {
        "latitude": 51.4935657,
        "longitude": -0.1465538
    }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "beaconName": "beacons/3!d31d9fdb7e38e787f8f75d5b6bd7df6f",
  "advertisedId": {
    "type": "EDDYSTONE",
    "id": "0x2f234454f4911ba9ffbw=="
  },
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "latLng": {
    "latitude": 51.4935657,
    "longitude": -0.14655379999999998
  }
}
```

If you notice carefully, the UID in the response does not match with the UID in POST request. Also, I tried the https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons?q=status:active GET and I am still seeing slightly different UID.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the strings you have in your code above are not actually what's being sent around because they shouldn't work at all.

There *is* an issue where: if you base64 encode the **hex** representation of the beaconID, and NOT the **binary** representation. It looks as though the server would erroneously accept this, but interpret it differently. That will be fixed soon.

So, instead of doing this:

```
var b64id = Base64Encode("abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789");
```

You want to be doing:

```
var b64id = Base64Encode(HexToBinary("abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789"));
```

I.e.

if you have the hex string for the id: `abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789`, make sure that your code produces the base64 string: `q83vASNFZ4mrze8BI0VniQ==` — that is what you should be sending the server in the `"id"` field.

A BeaconID is 16 bytes long, that will show up as a 32 character hex string.  The resulting base64 string encoding that beaconID should be about 23-24 characters long.

Hope that helps.

Comment: My bad, I removed the asterisk (*) from UID. Rest everything is what I am sending and I am getting success 200